# Invalid point attack yields wrong results for low order points

Tags: elliptic-curves, attack

I've recently tried to replicate the results of the question Ruggero asked and which Samuel Neves answered here: [Understanding Twist Security with respect to short Weierstrass curves](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19877/understanding-twist-security-with-respect-to-short-weierstrass-curves?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In my attempt to replicate this, I found that the attack does not work for some points. Initially my assumption was that this was because the twist factor $d$ in my case was not $-1 \mod p$. Hence, I asked this question: [Invalid point attack on quadratic twist of Elliptic Curve when -1 is a quadratic residue](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/99151/invalid-point-attack-on-quadratic-twist-of-elliptic-curve-when-1-is-a-quadratic/99225). However, as I've explored further it became clear to me that this is not the reason the attack does not work. Instead, with the very code of the original answer I can also reliably demonstrate that a real implementation of an X-only ladder works for points of order 100+, but does not (reliably) work for points of lower order.

I've modified Samuel's script here to deterministically show this behavior for a point of order 7:

```
# Setup fields
p  = 2^127-1
d  = -1 # non square in the field
K  = GF(p)
K2.<z> = GF(p^2)

# this curve has prime order, but a 2^44-smooth twist
a  = -3
b  = 2045
E  = EllipticCurve(K, [a, b])
Et = EllipticCurve(K, [d^2*a, d^3*b])
E2 = EllipticCurve(K2, [a, b])

# precompute orders
print (E.order().factor());
print (Et.order().factor());
print (E2.order().factor());

# generate a discrete logarithm to solve
s  = 123456789123456789123456789
P  = E([0, 26743016104147931148362869907315104519])
Q  = s * P

P_ = E2.lift_x(K(163965092228135290549051973720749297665))

fact = 7

P_ *= Et.order() // fact

print(P_)

Q_ = s * P_ # query -- pretend this is done with an x-only ladder

# solve the log directly on E2
x1 = P_[0]
print("x1_p2", x1)
x2 = Q_[0]
s_ = E2.lift_x(x1).discrete_log(E2.lift_x(x2))

# map to Et (optional) and solve
x1  = d * P_[0]
print("x1_t", x1)
x2  = d * Q_[0]
s__ = Et.lift_x(x1).discrete_log(Et.lift_x(x2))

for result in [ 153050600407045353908344231774077597412, 109343643823296263382915152331234715795 ]:
    for x in [ K(result), K(result) * d ]:
        for c in [ Et, E2 ] :
            try:
                P = c.lift_x(x)
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)
                continue
            print(P, P.order())


print (s % fact)
print (s_, -s_ % fact) # either one or the other
print (s__, -s__ % fact) # either one or the other
```

The values 15305... and 1093... are those that an X-only ladder implementation gives when given the coordinates `x1_p1` or `x1_t`.

Note that this code and my X-only ladder implementation works perfectly for all points with order 73 or above. It just does not work for orders 3 or 7. Here is the output of the script:

```
170141183460469231713519983870624230867
3 * 7^2 * 73 * 207464639 * 4221589732069 * 18102941371909
3 * 7^2 * 73 * 207464639 * 4221589732069 * 18102941371909 * 170141183460469231713519983870624230867
(31638283026303721859929793126783073834 : 8180858091114185696092778095200036260*z + 4090429045557092848046389047600018130 : 1)
x1_p2 31638283026303721859929793126783073834
x1_t 138502900434165509871757510589101031893
No point with x-coordinate 153050600407045353908344231774077597412 on Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 170141183460469231731687303715884105724*x + 170141183460469231731687303715884103682 over Finite Field of size 170141183460469231731687303715884105727
(153050600407045353908344231774077597412 : 120638375417041763806996747829917991029*z + 145389779438755497769342025772901048378 : 1) 56713727820156410583284874520381326863
(17090583053423877823343071941806508315 : 41244633631159509998704366741778119200 : 1) 56713727820156410583284874520381326863
(17090583053423877823343071941806508315 : 28961826547573943769330362324255518848 : 1) 170141183460469231713519983870624230867
No point with x-coordinate 109343643823296263382915152331234715795 on Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 170141183460469231731687303715884105724*x + 170141183460469231731687303715884103682 over Finite Field of size 170141183460469231731687303715884105727
(109343643823296263382915152331234715795 : 127120934962706688155967022405858199927 : 1) 170141183460469231713519983870624230867
No point with x-coordinate 60797539637172968348772151384649389932 on Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 170141183460469231731687303715884105724*x + 170141183460469231731687303715884103682 over Finite Field of size 170141183460469231731687303715884105727
(60797539637172968348772151384649389932 : 17145369941110587676988010143957064222 : 1) 170141183460469231713519983870624230867
1
1 6
1 6
```

Why does this attack work in theory (as the multiplication `Q_ = s * P_` simulates) but works in practice only for reasonably high order points?

Comment: I think one missing component of this question is what $x$-only ladder are you using to get those points?

Comment: Hi Samuel, I'm using the Brier and Joye implementation "Weierstraß Elliptic Curves and
Side-Channel Attacks", Fig. 3 with formulas (6) and (7). I've also found in a different paper a multiplicative point X coordinate addition formula, but it yields the exact same results as the additive formula of Brier and Joye. Is there any other algorithm that I shoulds use? And which would be the correct way, usinig the X coordinate of E_t or E_p² as input? I'm just confused as my approach works for all high-order points, it only fails for these very low order points.

Comment: I cannot verify this right now, but I seem to recall that the Brier-Joye formulas are not exception-free, and with low-order points you are likely to run into one such exception that renders the result incorrect (e.g., dealing with the point at infinity).

Comment: Dang! Spot on! I did some detailed debugging and what you described is exactly the case. Specifically, there are cases in which intermediate values become the point at infinity and if not handled as a special case, the computation is garbage. Also spot on that this likelihood is increased by low-order points. Thank you so much, you're a legend! All works perfectly now!